# Lucene pagination with TopScoreDocCollector

Tags: lucene

I have a code like this with Lucene. Can someone provide a sample or tips about how to make the pagination with Lucene?

```
    Query q = queryParser.parse(useQuery);
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(maxReturn, true);
searcher.search(q, collector);
```

Thanks.

Comment: check the approved answer in this post:
[Lucene 4 Pagination][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24533377/1080485

Answer (score 3):

You can get the TopDocs representing a particular page of results, using [TopDocsCollector.topDocs(int)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocsCollector.html#topDocs%28int%29).  Remember that the `start` argument represents how many documents in it should start, not how many "pages", so something like:

```
TopDocs hits = collector.topDocs(maxReturn*page);
```

Is usually appropriate (where `page` is numbered from 0)

Comment: How do I combine this with a `Sort` object? I'd like to sort and then extract a slice from that.

Comment: @Michael-O You don't.  Using a `TopScoreDocCollector` with a `Sort` doesn't make sense.  `TopScoreDocCollector` explicitly sorts by top score.  If you prefer to use a collector, use [`TopFieldCollector`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TopFieldCollector.html) instead.  You can also just call `IndexSearcher.search(Query query, int n, Sort sort)` for a first query, and then for subsequent pages, call `IndexSearcher.searchAfter(ScoreDoc after, Query query, int n, Sort sort)`, passing the last result returned as the "after" argument.

Comment: OK, thanks. I do already use the mentioned `search` method but the `searchAfter` won't help because I do expose them with an REST API and I do not have the `after` doc on a subsequent call. I would need something like `search(query, from, size, sort)`. Neither `TopScopeDocC...`, `TopFieldC...` not `searchAfter` will do, unfortunately. The only option I see is getting all `ScoreDocs` and implement the pagination manually.