# How to implement Proper Pagination in millions of records in Lucene

Tags: java, pagination, lucene

I have over 10 million Documents in my Lucene Indexes and I need to implement PROPER pagination in my application. Each document is a unique record of a College Candidate. Currently I am showing 5 records per page and providing pagination on the front end for the User.

As soon as the search is performed, 5 records are displayed for Page Number 1. Now there are buttons that takes the User to the First Page, Next Page, Previous Page and Last Page.

Now For example my search query has total hits of 10 million, and when I click on Last Page, I am basically going to Page Number 2000000(2 Million). In the back end I am passing pageNumber*5 as the maxSearch(int) in lucene search Function. This takes so much of time to fetch the results.

Please refer screenshot to see the result on front end [image: Screenshot]

And this is what I am doing on the back end,

[image: Backend Code][image: Backend Code 2]

My hits are never calculated. The process gets stuck at search. Kindly suggest me a solution to implement correct solution.

P.S. I am Using Lucene 4.0.0.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image.

Answer (score 2):

Several approaches might help:

## Leave all pagination to Lucene

You can avoid manual loop iteration over `hits.ScoreDocs` as described in accepted answer in [Lucene 4 Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589186/lucene-4-pagination/24533377#24533377) question.

## Cursors

If performance of Lucene-based pagination approach is not enough, you can try to implement cursors:

Any (found) document has a sort position, for example a tuple `(sort field value, docId)`. Second tuple element eliminates same sort value issue.

So you can pass sorting position to next and previous page and use sort filters instead of iteration.

#### For example:

In first page we see three documents (sorted by date):
`(date: 2017-01-01, docId: 10)`, `(date: 2017-02-02, docId: 3)`, `(date: 2017-02-02, docId: 5)`.

Second page will start from first (by sort) document with `(date >= 2017-02-02 OR (date == 2017-02-02 AND docId > 5)`.

Also it possible to cache this positions for several pages during search.

#### Pagination issues on changing index

Pagination usually applies to particular index version (if index updated in middle of user interaction with results pagination may provide bad experience -- document positions may vary due to adding and removing rows or modification the sort field value of existing document).

Sometimes we must provide search results "at moment of search", displaying a "snapshot" of index, but it is very tricky to big indexes.

Cursors that stored at client side (commonly as opaque string) can seriously break pagination when index is updated.

Usually, there are a few queries that provide really huge results and page cursors can be cached by backend using `WeakMap` over `coreCacheKey` for this queries.

## Special last page handling

If and only if "Last page" is a frequent operation, you can sort results in reverse order and obtain last page documents as a reverse of top reversed results.

Keep in the mind same value issue when implementing a reverse order.